# Personal Campaign Pages don't have a donate button

Tags: civicontribute, personal-campaign-pages, pcp

We are using version 4.6.3 on Drupal. Our Personal Campaign pages aren't displaying a donate button on them: it just has a link to have people make their own PCPs, and the honor roll and thermometer.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, I can see that the donation button only appears if `$validDate` is TRUE and `$contributeURL` is TRUE.

Enable debugging (**Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to "Enable Debugging"), then reload your PCP page, adding this to the end of the URL: `&smartyDebug=1`.  You'll get a pop-up showing all your Smarty variables.  Make sure that there's a value for both `$validDate` and `$contributeURL`.

My guess is either:

- You're before the PCP begin date;
- You're after the PCP end date;
- Your server has the wrong time set.

PS - also make sure there's a value set for `$contributionText`.  You can set this by editing the PCP and filling in the value for "Donation Button".

Comment: I am not seeing anything defined for $contributeURL or contributionText, but there is a value next to the Donation Button field on the PCP. The date of the campaign is also set to begin yesterday (and our server time is for today) and doesn't end until the 17th, but the $validDate is saying false.

Any advice on where I can  go to define the $contributeURL, or why the text isn't showing up despite the value next to the Donate Now?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in your last comment, I think the lack of donate button is indicative of a larger issue - this PCP isn't linked to a contribution page.  I don't know if this is a data issue or a bug; I don't have any PCP-using sites running 4.6 yet.

If you know how to use SQL, try running this statement on your Civi database:

```
SELECT id, page_id, page_type FROM civicrm_pcp;
```

The first `id` corresponds to the PCP id you see in the URL for that page.  `page_id` should be the contribution page it's linked to, and `page_type` should be "contribute".  If they're not, you could fix the SQL directly, or figure out what caused the PCP to not be linked to the 
contribution page.  If this doesn't answer your question, you may want to post the results of that SQL as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

We just had to resolve this for a site - in our case the client had fired up the PCPs using a Contribution Page which had an End Date set that was in the past - which is close to what Jon said above but for our case the solution is with the Contribion Page settings not the PCP settings